# Symfony2 Request-URI Too Long

Tags: php, symfony

I have action, but when i send data, i have

> Request-URI Too Long. The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $productGallery = new ProductGallery();
    $product = new Product();
    $productGallery->addProductgalleryToProduct($product);
    $form = $this->createForm(new ProductGalleryType(), $productGallery);
    if($request->isMethod('POST'))
    {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($productGallery);
            $em->persist($product);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('addAction', array('form' => $form->createView()));
        }
    }
    return array(
      'form' => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

How i can fixed it? What i do wrong?

p.s my form collection

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('productgallery_to_product', 'collection', array(
            'type'           => new ProductType(),
            'allow_add'      => true,
            'by_reference'   => false,
            'allow_delete'   => true,
            'prototype'      => true
        ))
    ;
}
```

NEW INFO

Method 'POST'
In my url

> http://trololo.com/app_dev.php/add?form%5Bvars%5D%5Bid%5D=games_modelbundle_productgallery&form%5Bvars%5D%5Bname%5D=games_modelbundle_productgallery&form%5Bvars%5D%5Bfull_name%5D=games_modelbundle_productgallery&form%5Bvars%5D%5Bdisabled%5D=0&form%5Bvars%5D%5Bmultipart%5D=1&form%5Bvars%5D%5Bblock_prefixes%5D%5B0%5D=form&form%5Bvars%5D%5Bblock_prefixes%5D%5B1%5D=games_modelbundle_productgallery&form%5Bvars%5D%5Bblock_prefixes%5D%5B2%5D=_games_modelbundle_productgallery&form%5Bvars%5D%5Bunique_block_prefix%5D=_games_modelbundle_productgallery&form%5Bvars%5D%5Bcache_key%5D=_games_modelbundle_productgallery_games_modelbundle_productgallery&form%5Bvars%5D%5Bread_only%5D=0&form%5Bvars%5D%5Bvalid%5D=1&form%5Bvars%5D%5Brequired%5D=1&form%5Bvars%5D%5Bcompound%5D=1&form%5Bvars%5D%5Bmethod%5D=POST&form%5Bvars%5D%5Baction%5D=&form%5Bvars%5D%5Bsubmitted%5D=1&form%5Bchildren%5D%5Bproductgallery_to_product%5D%5Bvars%5D%5Bid%5D=games_modelbundle_productgallery_productgallery_to_product&form%5Bchildren%5D%5Bproductgallery_to_product%5D%5Bvars%5D%5Bname%5D=productgallery_to_product&form%5Bchildren%5D%5Bproductgallery_to_product%5D%5Bvars%5D%5Bfull_name%5D=games_modelbundle_productgallery%5Bproductgallery_to_product%5D&form%5Bchildren%5D%5Bproductgallery_to_product%5D%5Bvars%5D%5Bdisabled%5D=0&form%5Bchildren%5D%5Bproductgallery_to_product%5D%5Bvars%5D%5Bmultipart%5D=1&form%5Bchildren%5D%5Bproductgallery_to_product%5D%5Bvars%5D%5Bblock_prefixes%5D%5B0%5D=form&form%5Bchildren%5D%5Bproductgallery_to_product%5D%5Bvars%5D%5Bblock_prefixes%5D%5B1%5D=collection&form%5Bchildren%5D%5Bprodu.....

Comment: What URI is it requesting? And are you submitting your form using `GET` rather than `POST` by any chance?

Comment: @Qoop update question

Comment: @Qoop have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a whole form view object in the URL:

```php
$this->redirectToRoute('addAction', array('form' => $form->createView()));
```

The second argument to `redirectToRoute()` is a list of GET parameters to send with the request.

This makes your URL VERY long. It exceeds the web server limit, which in turn refuses to handle the request.

Your call should look more like this:

```php
$this->redirectToRoute('addAction');
```

Also, the first argument to the `redirectToRoute()` method is the route name, not the action method name. Replace it unless your route name is "addAction".

Read more in the [Controller chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html) of the documentation.

Comment: So what can we do if we need to pass this information to the next controller? The information in my case comes from the same controller and I would like to pass this information to the next controller.



Can we pass throw the function redirectToRoute or redirect (I know that redirectToRoute is using redirect) this information via post somehow? Or perhaps another solution?